# Question about the meaning of "apply" and "confined" in this sentence

Tags: word-meaning

> **Azulfidine is classified as an anti-inflammatory agent and applies confined anti-inflammatory effects.**

my concerns firstly has to do with what the definition of **apply** here is and secondly if the word **confined** is an adjective here or it is passive form of the verb confine.

Comment: This sentence doesn't make sense. Can you please check whether it is written here as in the original document (and if you found it on-line can you please provide the link)?

Comment: @Lucky - Sorry, buddy. Yes, both are anti . I am going to correct it.

Comment: I understood that ‘unty’ was a typo, but the whole construction ‘applies confined anti-inflammatory effects’ doesn’t make sense to me, so I thought that there might be an error (e.g. a word or group of words being accidentally omitted in a copy-paste process) somewhere in it. I can take it apart grammatically, but I have read a lot of medical texts (in English) and have never, ever, seen a phrase like this one. If it’s not an error I suspect that it has been written either by someone who is not a native English speaker, or someone who understands next to nothing about pharmacology. Or both...

Comment: It might mean that the medicine will have (*apply = manifest, exert* in this context) a somewhat limited anti-inflammatory effect (the anti-inflammatory effect would be confined to... but it doesn't say what - certain body parts/organs? Some signs of inflammation?). But these would be only speculations, and medical texts are not (or at least shouldn't be) written ambiguously. If you have a link to the full text, that would be great.

Comment: @lucky - I found it in an android app. I couldn't agree more that "apply effect" mean "to have effect"  And you mean this is not good English, don't you? How would you paraphrase it?

Comment: Without more context I can't really say. It might be good English and terrible pharmacology, but this would be off topic here.

Comment: If I had been provided with more context there, I would have had quoted that here.

Comment: Possibly they were aiming for "topical".

Comment: You might try here: http://health.stackexchange.com/. For future ELL questions I would suggest that you include everything you know in the original question, instead of providing details in the comments (e.g. the source of the sentence - an android app, that this is all that the app says etc.). I hope you will find an answer to your question somewhere :-)

Answer (score 1):

Did you mistype this and mean:

> Azulfidine is classified as an anti-inflammatory agent and applies confined *anti*-inflammatory effects

It means anti-inflammatory effects are applied in a confined (restricted, delineated) manner.  This is fine, *confined* modifies *effects*, not *applies*.

Comment: 's - Thanks buddy. I meant to write anti but yes it was a typo. And when we say those effects of the medicine are applied in restricted manner, what the word "apply" mean?